# Sql Report Builder remove extra rows

Tags: reporting-services

I recently started using Sql Report Builder and I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why are there some extra rows on my data.

Basically the grouping is, Referencia > Localizacao > Etiqueta, as you can see from the image. I tried checking my data directly from SQL but everything is correct and these extra rows make no sense to me. If I remove the Details group these rows disappear but then my Etiquetas aren't grouped by Localizacao

[image]

**UPDATE**

Here is the design view

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a picture of your report in design view?

Comment: i will update tomorrow when im at office, i have no access to it right now. Tho, all I did was create a tablix, add Etiquetas, then add a parent group to etiquetas as Localizacao, then add a group parent to localizacao as Referencia and on that group add the rest as static columns. I can' see why it created these empty rows

Comment: I have updated with design view, please see :)